# Java code for remote date of other server doesn't run in windows XP (it runs in Windows 8)

Tags: java, windows, remote-access

I have this code for remote date. Could anyone help me understand how to get this to work in Windows XP or show me code for the same purpose that runs in Windows XP?

Thank you very much.

```
try {
    Date remoteDate = null;
    URL url = new URL("https://www.google.gr/?gws_rd=ssl");
    URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection conn1 = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
    conn1.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    conn1.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn1.setInstanceFollowRedirects( true );
    conn1.setRequestProperty( "User-agent", "spider" );
    conn1.connect();
    Map<String,List<String>> header = conn1.getHeaderFields();
    for (String key : header.keySet()) {
        if (key != null && "Date".equals(key)) {
            List<String> data = header.get(key);
            String dateString = data.get(0);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            try {
                remoteDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
                System.out.print("hi"+remoteDate);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JFrame0.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            break;
        } 
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JFrame0.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I've just installed Netbeans and the error is:

```
SEVERE: null
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 03 Dec 2014 10:18:09 GMT"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parseenter code here(DateFormat.java:357)
        at ast_v1.JFrame0.<init>(JFrame0.java:215)
        at ast_v1.JFrame0$18.run(JFrame0.java:1596)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1106)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:955)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:948)
        at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:336)
        at ast_v1.JFrame0.<init>(JFrame0.java:224)
        at ast_v1.JFrame0$18.run(JFrame0.java:1596)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Are you saying it works on other operating systems? if so which one(s)?

Comment: i have checked it in windows 8 for example,and it works.But it doesn't work in XP.

Comment: Which error do you get or why doesn't it work?

Comment: I can't check the error because i run an application.jar  file for a pc in my network that has windows XP and when i add this part of code,doesn't open the Frame.When i delete this code,it run normally.
Is there any way to look the error?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possbile problems in your source code, both are related to the formatter definition:

1. You don't specify the locale. You are retrieving the english localized day in week `Wed`. When running your program on a e.g. german PC the formatter will not detect `Wed` as day in week.
2. You do not specifiy the timezone in the formatter pattern. This is relevant if the received time stamp has a different time zone than your PC has.

So instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

use

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Does that answer your question? In such a case please mark your question as resolved. Thanks!